# Using Esri basemap in commercial media

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, license, arcgis-online-basemaps

Is a user with a valid ArcGIS Pro license allowed to use a map image which uses Esri basemaps (Oceans and terrain) in commercial print media?

If so, how should source be cited in the map?

If not, suggestions for how to provide necessary map media for magazine article?

Landsat imagery may be quite cloudy in the region of interest (Tierra del Fuego), and I need some sort of ocean bathymetry basemap as well.

I'm used to academic uses, and am unfamiliar with permissions for commercial uses.

Are there any examples of Esri map images in magazines / media?

Comment: There's a thread https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-osm-editor/issues/104 which has a few points of interest but all the links are 404:Not found. Even though Esri provides the service the data is from other sources, there is a citations layer in the basemap and on the lower right of the map there is a folder looking icon, click on it and you should see some metadata which should show the real contributors. Perhaps ask Esri directly or the contributors directly what the EULA allows before you start selling their data - in this case it is better to ask before rather than make reparations after.

Comment: Michael, make your comment an answer and I'll vote for it!